# Permissions issue with users having same group

Tags: ssh, permissions

USER  A need to execute a shell script from a Jenkins job (using SSH plugin), scripts reside in an AIX directory, belonging  to USER B. Both the users belong to same group. 
Script basically deploys TAR files and run chmod on the deployed files which grants access to USER B so that he can work with those files.

One solution would be that: Why don't use run the damn script from USER B account
Reason: Cause USER B is a generic account and it doesn't have the privilege of logging in using a SSH session. So I have to log in first using my N/W login and then switch to USER B.

Comment: It may help if you share the method you are using to grant access to the group.  If all is correct your method should work.